# Why is my view not visible?

Tags: android, view, opengl-es, android-linearlayout

I am trying to create another view on top of my GLSurfaceView, I have managed to do this before but for some reason nothing is visible this time round. I do all this in code but below is how it should work with XML:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
adLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.AdLinearLayout);

//If ad is found on server...Do this (view is passed into the method)
LayoutParams layout = new LayoutParams(adLinearLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), (adLinearLayout.getMeasuredWidth()*10)/64);
adView.setLayoutParams(layout);
adLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
adLinearLayout.addView(adView);
```

And my interpretation of this is:

```
glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
glView.setRenderer(this);
setContentView(glView);
adLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
adLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
this.addContentView(adLinearLayout, new LayoutParams(480, 150));

//If ad is found on server...Do This  (view is passed into the method)
LayoutParams layout = new LayoutParams(adLinearLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), (adLinearLayout.getMeasuredWidth()*10)/64);
view.setLayoutParams(layout);
adLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
adLinearLayout.addView(view, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

This never shows in the view on the screen though, is there something missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a framelayout to stack 2 views on top of each other.

Im not sure how you got overlapping done with linearlayout earlier. But by definition LinearLayout is used to asseble child views in either horizontal or vertical order.

About the frame layout, this is from the android docs

> Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child
>   on top. The size of the FrameLayout is the size of its largest child
>   (plus padding), visible or not (if the FrameLayout's parent permits).

You could also achieve some overlapping with a RelativeLayout but FrameLayout is the proper way to go.

Comment: I have used linearlayouts on top of another before though, tried to change it but it still doesnt work

Comment: I am trying to implement TapJoy's SDK and they are able to use LinearLayouts with this as well. In my previous project I add a LinearLayout ontop of the GLView, its not the case I am adding multiple layouts into a LinearLayout